# PhpStorm Structural Search, Contained in constraints syntax, how to search for tag, enclosed by tag?

Tags: search, constraints, phpstorm, structural-search

I want to search for a `footag` with attribute `foo=bar`, enclosed by `bartag` with `other=stuff`.

like a

```
<bartag other="stuff">
     ...
     <footag foo="bar">
     ...
</bartag>
```

In PhpStorm structural search I find [this template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXb2W.png). I really was wondering how it works and have find out that it's drive by this [magical condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zik97.png)

```
<'_tag:[regex( ul|ol )] /
```

What is this syntax? How it works?